# SQL Replace date in string

Tags: sql, date, replace, sql-server-2012

I have a string file name that are not always the same and I'm struggling to come up with something clean and not too cubersome that will strip out the date portion of the sting and replace it with yyyyMMdd or yyMMdd (depending upon the filename string format).

For example if the filename look like this:

```
g_monthlysales_20130930_2500g.txt
```

I'd like to convert it to this:

```
g_monthlysales_yyyyMMdd_2500g.txt
```

Or if the filename look like this:

```
gx130930rtwtg.txt
```

I'd like to convert it to this:

```
 gxyyMMddrtwtg.txt
```

These are the only two date formats that are possible for the file name and for the most part the dates are in the same position but the other file name characters will be different, for example I also have `sx141001theuf.txt` or `h_monthlysales_20130930_1000v.txt`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I would split that task into two steps. 1) Get the number from the string 2) Convert the number to date (say the function that loops through the formats that are acceptable for your region).

Comment: How many different date formats are you looking at here?

Comment: September doesn't have 31 days. Do you want to  detect only correct dates in your strings?

Comment: Edits made above for details regarding possible date formats. That was my mistake, the dates in the strings will always be valid dates so its not necessary to verify them.

Comment: *for the most part the dates are in the same position*  -- So you don't just have two filename formats?  How many variations could there be?

Answer (score 0):

If dates are always in the same position and files are always in the same format this code should work:

```
declare @testString nvarchar(100)
declare @result nvarchar(100)

set @testString = 'h_monthlysales_20130930_1000v.txt'
-- set @testString = 'g_monthlysales_20130930_2500g.txt'
-- set @testString = 'gx130930rtwtg.txt'
-- set @testString = 'sx141001theuf.txt'

IF patindex('_______________[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_.txt',@testString) = 1
BEGIN
    set @result = SUBSTRING(@testString,1,15)+'yyyyMMdd'+SUBSTRING(@testString,24,100)
END
ELSE IF patindex('__[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_____.txt',@testString) = 1
BEGIN
    set @result = SUBSTRING(@testString,1,2)+'yyMMdd'+SUBSTRING(@testString,9,100)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    set @result = @testString
END

print @result
```

If date can change position then something like this will work if date is always first numerical value(for second date format write similar code):

```
declare @testString nvarchar(100)
declare @result nvarchar(100)
declare @datePostion int

--set @testString = 'h_monthlysales_20130930_1000v.txt'
set @testString = 'g_monthlysalesxyz_20130930_2500g.txt'

set @datePostion = patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%.txt',@testString)
IF @datePostion > 0
BEGIN   
    set @result = SUBSTRING(@testString,1,@datePostion-1)+'yyyyMMdd'+SUBSTRING(@testString,@datePostion+8,100)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    set @result = @testString
END

print @result
```

Comment: Why not just use a `case` expression instead of all those `if` blocks?

Comment: I am more used to if than case :). Also in second example, when date can change position, in case syntax you will have to execute patindex three times. First to check if condition is fulfilled, and then twice when building result - maybe it is possible to optimize it.

Comment: Working within SQL databases, a set based solution such as mine will almost always perform better than a value by value or row by row approach, which is the only way your solution can be implemented on more than one filename.

Answer (score 0):

This will find any 8 digit number first, then any 6 digit number and try to turn it into a `date` value.  This will work with the dates anywhere in the filename though will almost certainly give awful performance:

```
declare @t table(f varchar(50));
insert into @t values('g_monthlysales_20130930_2500g.txt'),('gx130930rtwtg.txt'),('sx141001theuf.txt'),('h_monthlysales_20130930_1000v.txt');

select f
      ,case when patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',f) > 0
            then convert(date,substring(f,patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',f),8),112)
            else convert(date,substring(f,patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',f),6),12)
            end as d
from @t;
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|                 f                 |      d     |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
| g_monthlysales_20130930_2500g.txt | 30.09.2013 |
| gx130930rtwtg.txt                 | 30.09.2013 |
| sx141001theuf.txt                 | 01.10.2014 |
| h_monthlysales_20130930_1000v.txt | 30.09.2013 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

---

If you can either find all the possible formats or better yet change your import routines to have a consistent filename format you can make this query a lot more efficient through a lack of wildcards being necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question correctly, we're not trying isolate the dates, we're trying to overwrite them. This should do that, or get you headed in that direction anyway.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (FileNme VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO
  @t
VALUES
  ('g_monthlysales_20130930_2500g.txt')
 ,('gx130930rtwtg.txt')
 ,('sx141001theuf.txt')
 ,('h_monthlysales_20130930_1000v.txt');

SELECT
  FileNme
 ,CASE
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', FileNme) > 0 
      THEN STUFF(FileNme, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', FileNme), 8, 'yyyyMMdd')
    ELSE STUFF(FileNme, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', FileNme), 6, 'yyMMdd')
  END AS NewNme
FROM
  @t;
```

Results:

```
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|              FileNme              |              NewNme               |
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| g_monthlysales_20130930_2500g.txt | g_monthlysales_yyyyMMdd_2500g.txt |
| gx130930rtwtg.txt                 | gxyyMMddrtwtg.txt                 |
| sx141001theuf.txt                 | sxyyMMddtheuf.txt                 |
| h_monthlysales_20130930_1000v.txt | h_monthlysales_yyyyMMdd_1000v.txt |
+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```